# MariaDB audit plugin logs all queries instead of DML only

Tags: audit, mariadb-10.1

I was testing the "server_audit" plugin of MariaDB, which I configured like this:

```
plugin-load-add = server_audit
server_audit_logging = ON
server_audit_events = QUERY_DML
server_audit_output_type = FILE
server_audit_file_path = /path/to/audit.log
server_audit_query_log_limit = 1048576
server_audit_file_rotate_size = 1073741824
server_audit_file_rotations = 1
```

and I am currently running `MariaDB 10.1.29` with `MariaDB Audit Plugin version 1.4.3`.

Based on [the docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-audit-plugin-log-settings/), the value `QUERY_DML` should be

> Same as QUERY, **but filters only DML-type queries (DO, CALL, LOAD DATA/XML, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, HANDLER and REPLACE statements)**

emphasis mine.

After restarting the server, the log files has correctly been created, however it is logging also other queries, like for example plain `SELECT`s.

Is my configuration somewhat incorrect, or is it perhaps an error on MariaDB side?

Comment: It is very possible that SELECT is considered DML - though the documentation doesn't specify this, maybe because of an error. But the key here is "for example". Which other queries are logged?

Comment: The other queries logged in the few tests I made were `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s as expected.. I'd find it strange if `SELECT`s were considered data "manipulation" queries, since they do not change data, but it could be just me being ignorant.

Comment: I agree with you about the definition of DML, but if the only "wrong" logged query is SELECT, I suppose that SELECT has been considered DML. You may want to report a bug stating that the actual behaviour is inconsistent with the documentation.

Comment: I reported it as possible bug at https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15480, let see what is the response.

Comment: Good. I subscribed to the bug, as I'm currently evaluating an auditing solution.

Comment: DML does often include SELECT statements, though they are also sometimes considered part of a separate Data Query Language - DQL, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 1.4.4 of the [plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-audit-plugin-log-settings/), there is now a `QUERY_DML_NO_SELECT` type that should give you what you are expecting.

> Same as QUERY_DML, but doesn't log SELECT queries. (since version 1.4.4) (DO, CALL, LOAD DATA/XML, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, HANDLER and REPLACE statements)

This was introduced in MariaDB 5.5.42, MariaDB 10.0.17, and MariaDB 10.1.4.